# Accessing model in controller equals nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got the following problem
I have a model called Article, which I access at two points.
First at the "home-page ( root )" I just do Article.all and list all of them.
That works fine for me, but whenever I access Article.all on my admin-panel ( /admin/articles ) it just says the following:
[image]

My controller looks like this:

```
def index
    @news = Article.all
end
```

My model can be accessed easily in the rails console:
[image]

All of this is somehow solved by opening the controller and just re-saving it.
After a rails restart or logout and login on the site it is broken again

Comment: This must be an issue of namespaces and routings, somewhat related to scope module: 'admin' do
  resources :articles
end

Comment: I think your index action is not been called, just put a `puts 'something'` in it, and see. This is for sure a routing error. do you have two controllers named `articles_controller` one under admin and the other directely under the controllers folder. If so, check out your routes and see if your controller is accessible by your routes.

Comment: Hey, I've renamed everything and I made a new controller called different than Article and it seems to be working now, thanks for the help. I don't see thos why that shouldn't work when it is in a namespace

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to organize groups of controllers under a namespace. Most commonly, you might group a number of administrative controllers under an

Admin:: namespace.

At the console:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :articles
end
```

This will create a number of routes for each of the articles

use one of the routes to access your controller from Admin

Comment: I already have it under a namespace, I had to rename the controller from Articles for some reason, thanks for the attempt tho!

Answer (score 0):

Try converting to array,

```
@news.to_a.count
```